# App shows loading forever after tapping Cancel while picking image for upload

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, ios-app, uploader

**Description:**

When tapping the Cancel button while choosing an image or taking a photo for upload, it shows the loading indicator forever.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open the left drawer, and tap **Ask Question**.
2. Tap **Question body goes here...** to select the question body.
3. Tap the **brush icon** above the keyboard, then tap the **camera icon**.
4. In the "Choose source" action sheet, choose either **Photo Library** or **Camera**.
5. In the new view, tap **Cancel**.

**Actual Results:**

It shows the loading indicator forever.

**Expected Results:**

It shouldn't show a loading indicator. I should be able to continue writing my question.

**Environment:**

- Stack Exchange iOS App v0.1.49
- iPhone 5
- iOS 7.1

Comment: Reproduced. And adding an answer does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the report. I am taking a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed on **version 0.1.50.**.

Comment: Verified fixed in v0.1.50.